# Complex argument and complex log function.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In my whole question $\arg(z), \operatorname{Arg}(z), \log(z)$ and $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ are general argument, principal argument, general logarithm and principal logarithm respectively which are defied for non zero complex numbers and $n\in\mathbb N$. Now I observed the following

$a.$ $\arg(z^n)=n \arg(z) $ for  $z\neq 0$.

$b.$ $\operatorname{Arg}(z^n)= n\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is not true in general as $n\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ may not lies in range $(-\pi,\pi]$.

$c$. $\arg(z^{1/n})=\frac{1}{n}\arg(z)$ by considering $z=e^{i\theta}$ we get $z^{1/n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}i\theta}$.

$d.$  $\operatorname{Arg}(z^{1/n})=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ because $\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ lies inside range $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Now **if my above results are true** then can I conclude the following by using definition $$\log(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$$ and $$\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$$

$1$. $\log(z^n)=n\log(z)$ by using $a$.

$2$. $\operatorname{Log}(z^n)= n\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is not true in general  by using $b$.

$3.$ $\log(z^{1/n})=\frac{1}{n}\log(z)$ by using $c$.

$4.$ $\operatorname{Log}(z^{1/n})=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Log}(z)$ by using $d$?

If these are not true then which one is not true any why. Thank you.

Comment: I guess I would state 2. as "there exist $z$ such that..", rather than a blanket not equals.

Comment: @copper.hat yes sir correct edited

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "general logarithm". Also, does ${\rm Log}((-1)^{1/2})=(1/2){\rm Log}(-1)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson both of these value are equal to $\frac{i\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I defied $log(z) $ and $Log(z)$ as general and principal one .

Comment: Yes, but as I told you, I don't know what you mean by "general logarithm". And the principal branch of the logarithm isn't defined on the negative reals, right? So ${\rm Log}(-1)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I though principal branch is defined on full complex plane except zero and is not analytic on negative real part . Am I wrong ?

Comment: No, you're right – but I don't like defining it that way. I'd rather have it be analytic function on its domain, and for that, one must exclude to nonpositive reals from its domain.

Comment: the problem with a is that defining the argument that way makes the arguments of $z^n$ quite discontinuous which doesn't matter for integral $n$ by periodicity but matters for other $n$ and for the logarithm of $z^n$ rendering it useless for practical purposes;